# The @printf macro produces errors with a predefined format string

Tags: julia

When running Julia 1.0.0 the @printf macro seems to **not be able** to accept either a constant format string or a variable format string.  This is shown below.

```
julia> using Printf

julia> const fmt = "%10d %6.4f"
"%10d %6.4f"

julia> @printf(fmt, 101, 65.4039)
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: @printf: first or second argument must be a format string

julia> fmt2 = "%10d %6.4f"
"%10d %6.4f"

julia> @printf(fmt2, 101, 65.4039)
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: @printf: first or second argument must be a format string
```

I found a [discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4248) for an early version of Julia (2013) where this kind of thing was not allowed.

I see in the 1.0.0 [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Printf/#Printf-1) for `@printf` the following syntax:

```
@printf([io::IOStream], "%Fmt", args...)
```

Does this imply that `"@Fmt"` must be hardcoded into the `@printf` parameters when called?

Has anything changed with regard to using a dynamic format string since 2013 with  regard to Julia's `@printf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see by inspecting the [implementation](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/e7d15d4a013a43442b75ba4e477382804fa4ac49/stdlib/Printf/src/Printf.jl#L34) of `@printf` this is currently not supported. Note that it checks for `args[1] isa AbstractString` which isn't true in your example (where `typeof(args[1]) == Symbol`).

If you feel this should be added, you could file a feature request [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/new).

**UPDATE:**

Actually I should have read the github issue that you linked. Although it still isn't supported the way you want it, there are nice ways to handle cases like this. As has been suggested by Stefan [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4248#issuecomment-24199496) you can do:

```
julia> using Printf

julia> const fmt = "%10d %6.4f"
"%10d %6.4f"

julia> @eval myprintf(x,y) = @printf($fmt,x,y)
myprintf (generic function with 1 method)

julia> myprintf(101, 65.4039)
       101 65.4039
```

This defines a (efficient) function `myprintf` which has the format string build in.

Comment: I was doing dynamic format strings years ago in Fortran.  Sorry to see it is not in Julia.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I added a request [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29278).  Hope I did it correctly.

Comment: @julialearner You can get dynamic format strings using the Formatting.jl package. Honestly, I used to feel like you that this should be in the base language, but my understanding is that to get super-fast printing with a codebase that was still relatively sane, the devs pretty much had to go the route they did. From what I've heard, the actual underlying code that allows dynamic format strings with super fast printing in C and Fortran is the stuff of nightmares.

Comment: But it was a cool feature of Fortran.  It is something I really used, but I have not used Fortran in about a decade or more.

Comment: I also wish dynamic format string will be implemented (natively) in Julia, such that n x (some format string) can be used on-the-fly (where n is a variable, not a constant).

Comment: Agree!  Maybe you should put in a request at the link provided in the answer?

Comment: @roygvib I edited my question so that a dynamic format string example is available for newcomers to Julia, like me.  Sadly it is not native Julia as you, and I, wish for.  I think a newcomer to Julia may be stopped by the details shown above, just to get dynamic format strings.

Comment: It seems that the issues you are pointing out (Pkg not defined, STDOUT not known) could be fixed in Formatting.jl in 5 minutes. Why not submit a PR instead of explaining how to work around those issues?

Comment: @julialearner Thanks for the info. I knew the name of this package (and similar string utils), but also read some threads in Discourse  about compatibility/maintanance issues, so have not tried them yet (hoping that such a functionality would be supported natively soon). Anyway, I will try it with v1.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Moved answer from an edit to the question, by [Julia Learner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10316987/julia-learner):

---

### Get a dynamic format string using the Formatting package

It appears that the use of @printf has not changed up to version 1.0.0.

For anyone else wanting a dynamic format string capability, here is what I have found for Julia 1.0.0 and the 9/20/2018 version of the Formatting package.  From its [documentation](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl/blob/master/README.md)

> This package is pure Julia. Setting up this package is like setting up other Julia packages:
>
> Pkg.add("Formatting")

You will probably get an error **error** using 1.0.0:

```
julia>  Pkg.add("Formatting")
ERROR: UndefVarError: Pkg not defined
```

***Solution:** Access the new package manager in Julia 1.0.0 with the ] key, see [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/#Adding-packages-1).

**Note:** The following command is case sensitive, `add formatting` will fail.

```
(v1.0) pkg> add Formatting
```

Now your first test of `printfmt` may fail as shown:

```
julia> printfmt("Testing")
ERROR: UndefVarError: STDOUT not defined
```

**Solution:** Add a standard out parameter and spell `stdout` in lowercase:

```
julia> printfmt(stdout, "Testing")
Testing
```

Now we have a working dynamic format capability in Julia 1.0.0:

Next you may get the following error:

```
julia> const fmt = "%10d %6.4"
ERROR: cannot assign variable Formatting.fmt from module Main
```

**Solution:** Use a format variable name that does not conflict with the Formatting package.  Also note the use, in this example, of a Python-style format string:

```
julia> frmt = "{:10d} {:6.4f}"  # Python-style format string
"{:10d} {:6.4f}"

julia> printfmt(stdout, frmt, 10, 65.4039)
        10 65.4039
```